# Delivery of Remote Desktop Connection Data from Node.js Server to Client

Tags: node.js, powershell, client-side, remote-desktop, rdp

I want to create a Node.js server that allows clients to connect to virtual machines using the Remote Desktop Protocol.

My idea is for the server to generate an RDP file containing all the access data and provide it to the client, who can then execute it.

The issue is that it seems the RDP file must include an encrypted password. I don't know how to encrypt the password on the server side. I found that this can be done on the client side using shell commands like:

`"$password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) | ConvertFrom-SecureString"`

However, a password encrypted this way [can only be decrypted on the machine where it was encrypted](https://superuser.com/a/456800/1765086). This means I can't encrypt it on the server and use it on the client.

Is there a way to configure the client's browser to allow the execution of shell scripts on the client? I'm aware of the security risks, but I'd like to make it work at least for a prototype in a controlled environment.

Alternatively, is there another way to deliver Remote Desktop access data from the server, which the client could use to initiate the connection?